# Join results of two rest query and bind in a single object | RxJS + Angular 7

Tags: angular, rest, join, rxjs, angular7

I need an help, i've two rest query and i need to join in a single object.
So my two query i need to call:

```
this.http.get<Observable<Machine>>(Config.urlApi + 'machines')
this.http.get<Observable<MaintenanceState>>(Config.urlApi + 'MaintenanceStates/' + '300000')
```

Object returned of the first query (array object):

```
...
        {
        "mccId": 69,
        "mccSerialNum": "300000",
        "mccIsOnline": 0,
        "mccUsrId": 1,
        "mccTypeMachine": "tes",
        "mccEmailCustomer": "xxxx@xxxxx.it",
        "mccVersion": "2.0",
        "mccActivationDate": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
        "alrAlarms": [],
        "gpsGeolocations": [],
        "hrpHistoryRepo": []
    }
...
```

Object returned of the firs query:

```
{
    "mnsId": 22,
    "mnsMccId": 69,
    "mnsOrdinaria": false,
    "mnsBiennaleRfi": false,
    "mnsAnnuale": false,
    "mnsQuinquennale": false,
    "mnsFlag": null
}
```

So i would return like this:

```
{
    "mccId": 69,
    "mccSerialNum": "300000",
    "mccIsOnline": 0,
    "mccUsrId": 1,
    "mccTypeMachine": "tes",
    "mccEmailCustomer": "xxxx@xxxxx.it",
    "mccVersion": "2.0",
    "mccActivationDate": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
    "alrAlarms": [],
    "gpsGeolocations": [],
    "hrpHistoryRepo": [],
    // how to join this in the same object ?
    {
       "mnsId": 22,
       "mnsMccId": 69,
       "mnsOrdinaria": false,
       "mnsBiennaleRfi": false,
       "mnsAnnuale": false,
       "mnsQuinquennale": false,
       "mnsFlag": null
    }
}
```

So i'm new of RxJS and i'm trying to make this with rxJS and Angular 7
I need to call a second query after filter `mnsMccId` by the first query and for every object into array i need to put the second result of query.

My training code:

```
const values$ = this.http.get<Observable<Machine>>(Config.urlApi + 'machines')
  .pipe(
    tap(),
    map(res => this.http.get<Observable<MaintenanceState>>(Config.urlApi + 'MaintenanceStates/' + res.mccSerialNumber /*this id got by the first query*/))
  )
  .subscribe(res => {
    console.log('res: ', res);
  });
```

Clearly doesn't work, it's difficulty to understand for me. I'm new.
Thanks.

Comment: `objectFromFirstAPICall.Returned = objectFromSecondAPICall`?

Comment: Returned doesn't exist before, maybe i can add Returned after the first call ?

Comment: Make API call 1. In the subscribe callback make API call 2. In call 2's subscribe, concatenate. If you control the backend, you should probably concatenate there though.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.http.get<Observable<Machine>>(Config.urlApi + 'machines')
  .pipe(switchMap(res1 => {
    return this.http.get<Observable<MaintenanceState>>(Config.urlApi + 'MaintenanceStates/' + res1.mccSerialNumber)
      .pipe(map(res2 => ({...res1, ...res2})));
  })).subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: I tried your code, i've multiple Machine json, and your code join the second request at all array json on the first query. There's a method to join every res2 to res1 single object ?

Comment: @Mr.Developer so you are making once req1 and then many times req2? After every req2 you want join this response to that first req1? Join to object or some array field because it can override values?

Answer (score 0):

To do this reactively you should first get the two event streams and then merge in a later step.

```
const machines$ = this.http.get<Observable<Machine>>(Config.urlApi + 'machines');

const maintainenceStates$ = this.machines$.pipe(
  mergeMap(m => this.http.get<Observable<MaintenanceState>>(Config.urlApi + 'MaintenanceStates/' + m.mccSerialNum'))
);

const mappedData$ = zip(machines$, maintainenceStates$).pipe(
  map(values => map values here //you get an array of [machine, state])
);

mappedData$.subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: in the first request m.mccSerialNum i can't get single propertie because it's an array, maybe i need a forEach() or filter?